# Putting private data in JWT JSON web tokens

Tags: json, security, jwt

Is it acceptable to put private data (like an email address) in a JWT JSON Web Token?

The header and claims section are perfectly readable. You just base64 decode them. Does this mean my JWTs have to go over SSL?

Answer (score 1):

Are you protecting the data against:

1. The user of your application? (e.g. you want the user to "hold onto" a private email address that is used elsewhere in your application without having to store it server-side)
2. Eavesdroppers on the connection between your user and your server?

I suspect from your question that it is #2 you are seeking to protect against. If so, TLS/SSL is generally the recommended way to go. Without more details it is difficult to comment further, however ensuring your are communicating this email address over HTTPS only then this will generally secure it against eavesdroppers.

Comment: I've already got all our traffic going over SSL for this website, so no problems there. I am using the email address as an id for each user.